# Copied List Item Opens Wrong Item

Tags: list, workflow

I created a list template from an existing list without the data in it.  I only needed specific items so I created a workflow to pick and choose.  I set the workflow up to copy the item from List 1 -> List 2 and it worked fine.  But I have come to realize that the edit form in List 2 where the copied item now resides is opening the wrong list item.

Essentially, the new list item ID in List 2 is 10 but SharePoint is looking back to List 1 for item 10.  Is there a way to break this relationship?

Are there associations with the forms from list 1 or custom forms?

[image]

Comment: can you post  a screenshot of your WF?

Comment: updated original post